# Why does calling an external java function cause my app to crash? (Amazon SNS, S3)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are putting together an Unity app that uses Amazon S3 and SNS SDKs. On their own they're working fine - with SNS only the app registers and receives notifications properly, with S3 we can download images and videos fine.

Combining the SDKs into one app is now causing problems and after hours I have found the line that's causing the crash:

**GCM.cs**

```
string regId = cls.CallStatic<string>("register",senderIds);
```

What's odd is that ADB logcat is giving no errors at this point but after putting a return before then after this call it is known this is where the app crashes. Strangely the push registration process continues in ADB while the "This app has crashed" message is being displayed up until it completes with success as if the app starts up properly...

The "register" function being called is in **AWSUnityGCMWrapper.java**

```
public static String register(final String senderIds) {
    try {
        if (senderIds == null) {
            return "";
        }
        Activity activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity);
        String regId = gcm.register(senderIds);
        storeRegistrationId(activity, regId);
        return regId;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to register the to gcm");
        Log.e(TAG, "exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Tried many configs for the AndroidManifest.xml with no luck, except that all seems to be working fine through logcat! The CallStatic returns properly and the process continues nonetheless until 'ok' is pressed on the crash popup...

Any idea why this call static function is causing this problem? Ask for more code samples if needed!

Edit: **AndroidManifest.xml** if it helps...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.appname"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- PUSH --><uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- PUSH --><permission android:name="com.company.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!-- PUSH --><uses-permission android:name="com.company.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>

  <!-- PUSH --><receiver
      android:name="com.company.appname.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.company.appname" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  <!-- PUSH --><service android:name="com.company.appname.GCMIntentService" />

    <!--
        To support devices using the TI S3D library for stereo mode we must 
        add the following library.
        Devices that require this are: ODG X6 
    -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.ti.s3d" android:required="false" />
    <!--
        To support the ODG R7 in stereo mode we must add the following library.
    -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.osterhoutgroup.api.ext" android:required="false" />
</application>
```

**Edit** - **AWSUnityGCMWrapper.java Using AsyncTask**

```
public static String register(final String senderIds) {

    // Async Task
    _regID = "0";
    _done = false;

    new RegTask().execute(senderIds);

    while(!_done);

    return _regID;

}

public static void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void setReg(String regID) {
    _done = true;
    _regID = regID;
}

public static String getReg() {
    return _regID;
}

private static class RegTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String _regID;

    public RegTask() {
        super();
        _regID = "0";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, ">>> Registering With GCM Async Task... Sender: " + params[0]);
        String senderIds = params[0];
        try {
            if (senderIds == null) {
                //_regID = "0";
                return "0";
            }
            Log.i(TAG, ">>> Trying Registration...");
            Activity activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity);
            String regId = gcm.register(senderIds);
            Log.i(TAG, ">>> New Registration ID: " + regId);
            storeRegistrationId(activity, regId);
            //_regID = regId;
            return regId;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to register the to gcm");
            Log.e(TAG, "exception = " + e.getMessage());
        }

        //_regID = "0";
        Log.i(TAG, ">>> Registering With GCM Async Task Done...");
        return "0";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        setReg(result);
    }
}
```

**In Logcat**

I/AWSUnityGCMWrapper(21896): >>> Registering With GCM Async Task... Sender: 750882817708
I/AWSUnityGCMWrapper(23338): >>> New Registration ID: APA91bHWev8CCsbso8JE5a28J...
I/AWSUnityGCMWrapper(21896): Saving regId on app version 1

The app still crashes immediately when the register button is pressed.

Comment: Are you calling this on the main thread? Or somewhere else, like Update() in Unity? Edited: Try wrapping your java function in a UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  ...
 }
} or something close to that, this is known to cause problems if called otherwise.

Comment: The call is in a coroutine created through an unity objects 'start' function when the app is launched. I don't think it's a problem with the Java, something Unity side seems to be packing in as the call is made. I have tried moving the call to other places e.g. when everything else has finished (S3, other SDK setup) but same result...

Comment: Would you consider wrapping the inside of the function / making workaround to try and run it on UI thread anyway? This is something that has happened before to me, that's why I'd love to get this ticked off before diving in another possibilities.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do! Cheers

Comment: Seems to be a bit annoying to wrap it because of returning strings unless I'm missing something (been a while since using Java)

Comment: I guess you can get something returned outside of your wrapping as we just want to prevent crashes first.

Comment: Alright, out of time for now but I will try first thing tomorrow, wasn't expecting such quick replies! Cheers

Comment: I  wrapped the code in a runnable class and now run it like this:

`MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, senderIds);
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(r);`

The app no longer crashes but the code in the runnable is now giving the exception error: "failed to register the to gcm" and "exception = MAIN_THREAD" while before no exception was thrown, code continued to register properly but caused the crash...

Comment: So putting it in a new thread somehow makes it think it's running on the main thread which it wasn't before...

Comment: I'll write up an answer then, with possible solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to revert back to what I had originally and started stripping down the AndroidManifest.xml (lots of things in there from a colleague which seem to have been redundant). Using the following manifest seems to have solved the problem, there must have been something conflicting...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.appname"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
  android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:debuggable="true">

<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
</activity>

<receiver
     android:name="com.company.appname.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <category android:name="com.company.appname" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.company.appname.GCMIntentService" />
```

I will do some tests today and try to find out exactly what part was causing the problem.

Comment: @Obi-Dan Don't know if you will see this, but I am having a similar problem. Could you tell me which AndroidManifest.xml you modified to look like that? Since my unity projects contain several.

Answer (score 1):

So, from our discussion in comments under your post, your code for registering for GCM should be run in UI thread. Namely, you should wrap your function in a runOnUiThread(), which you did by:

1. Creating a Runnable class
   MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, senderIds);
2. Running it like so:
   UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(r);

What it does is no longer crashing up, but coming up with a exception thrown (which is just called MAIN_THREAD in your logs).

What you should do is instead of just calling .register(...) in your runnable function call it on the background, for example in an AsyncTask:

```
private void registerBackground(final String senderId) {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);


                String regId = gcm.register(senderId);
                storeRegistrationId(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, regId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            // msg returned
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
```

This is because UI operations on android happen on the main thread, but networking has to be done in a background one.

Call this instead of your register function and let me know if that helped.

Edit:

Btw, you might want to listen for changes or wait for them in a proper way since I can see your static f-tion returns the string.

Edit2:

So after my advice you've moved it to a proper async task. But there is another problem of waiting for a result. To do that you can write something like this instead of a while:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            _done = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

also in your task's onPostExecute() call this
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

Then, instead of a while() in your function make a runnable or another simple waiter. But for now, you might want to test it with Thread.sleep(1000); inside a while to ease the load on UI.

Comment: Ok thanks, created an AsyncTask (see edit in main post). I now seem to be getting past the gcm.register function and actually getting an ID back, the code continues into storeRegistrationID but then crashes there somewhere `>>> Registering With GCM Async Task Done...` never gets logged (because I return before that I just realised) and nothing else is output to Logcat.

Comment: editor.commit(); try changing that to .apply() instead of commit()

The "done" part never gets loged since you return your string before in a try block

Also, what's in your getGCMPreferences(...)?

Comment: Yep, realised that after replying, did another build with the while loop printing "Waiting...", it looks like it still crashes on register as "Saving regID on app..." doesn't show until the loop has been going for a second or two, I will try .apply() to see what happens

Comment: .apply() seems to stop the task ever finishing, "Waiting..." prints for ever, using commit the app still crashes but logcat is back to showing the app working as normal (all push registration goes through and works after crash...)

Comment: Thing is, doing a while() loop in your static function probably causes the crash. You'd need to maybe create a handler to set your flag instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've added another bit of replacing the while with something lighter, but for now just try putting Thread.sleep(1000); inside the while.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to implement the Handler here, added a sleep to the loop but it's still crashing before "Waiting" is even displayed for the first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95472/discussion-between-messer-and-obi-dan).

Comment: It's all good now (see the answer I posted) turns out it was something to do with the manifest.xml playing up. Thanks for attempting to help solve this annoying issue!